# Ganache UI infinite spinner / workspace not accesable

Tags: ganache, ganache-cli

I have been using Ganache UI for over a year now on CentOS7. But last week it hadn't been working correctly. Whenever I create a new Workspace and add a project, the UI gets stuck

For example: I open Ganache and everything seems normal at first.

[image: Gganache UI]

But as soon as I try to enter any of the **existing** projects,(For example: **Something-Something**) I just get the infinite spinner (picture below)

[image: Infinite Spinner]

Surprisingly, I am able to open the **Quickstart** option.

[image]

It's responsive and everything, I can even run tests on its blockchain. But as soon as I link a truffle project to it and click **"Save Workspace"**, I am back to the infinite spinner from the second screenshot.

[image: infinite Spinner again]

The same happens if I attempt to create a **"New Workspace"** from scratch. I link the **truffle-congif.js** and click **"Save Workspace"**, but it again results in an infinite spinner.

[image]

At first, I thought my project has an error, maybe in **truffle-confing.js**. But I pulled the **identical code** from GitHub to another Ubuntu machine with the **same version of Ganache** and it works there with no issues whatsoever.

I do have ganache-cli installed over the terminal, but it uses a different port, and I had never before had a problem of running both at the same time.

I also tried to re-install Ganache UI, but maybe I am doing something wrong there. I might need to purge the app or something. As even after I delete the app and download a new version, the old workspaces are still visible there on the starting screen.

All in all, I tried everything I could think of. The only thing left is to see if anyone else ever had a similar issue.